# ZTE Prelude 2, cricket wireless change over to tracfone

Tags: lock-screens

I just bought a used ZTE Prelude 2, a cricket wireless phone, but am trying to change over to tracfone. I followed all of the steps through tracfone, bought a sim kit and installed it, but now the phone is saying it is Perso locked. What does that mean, and how do i unlock so tracfone will take over?

Answer (score 0):

Perso locked in your case means that the phone is locked to cricket wireless, and it can't be used with other carriers unless you unlock it.

To unlock your phone, follow instructions below:

> Our phones work best on the Cricket network, but we'll provide the
>   unlock code if you meet the following requirements:
>
> - The device you want to unlock has been active for at least six (6)
>     months of paid service.*
> - The device you want to unlock is designed for use on and is currently locked to Cricket's network.
> - Your device hasn't been reported as lost or stolen. Your device isn't associated with a fraudulent account.
>
> *The 6 months paid service requirement does not apply to Cricket devices purchased by Unlimited Plan customers before January 4, 2018.
>
> If you meet these requirements and would like to unlock your device,
>   please call (1800-274-2538) a Cricket Support Advocate or visit your
>   local [Cricket Store](https://www.cricketwireless.com/map.html#stores)
>
> [Source](https://www.cricketwireless.com/support/apps-and-services/device-unlock/customer/device-unlock.html)

Comment: I was just about to leave a comment about Link-only answer...

Comment: And then what happened?

Comment: You expect anything to happen? Surely no. I realized it's a fine answer.